# Checking out a Linux-based subversion project into Windows and line endings

Tags: svn, eol

I am collaborating on a project hosted in a Subversion repository on a Linux server. My computer runs Windows XP. I am using CollabNet's Windows Subversion command-line client on my Windows XP machine.

I am running into the end-of-line (EOL) problem that happens when I edit a file on my Windows machine and then do an `svn update`. Subversion thinks there are differences when the only differences are really between line-endings.

I kow that this could be solved with the `eol-style` property, but I am unclear as how to proceed:

1. What setting for `eol-style` should I use?
2. Do I make this property setting on the Linux side or the Windows side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use `svn:eol-style= native`. This means that it'll convert LF to CRLF when on windows, and keep LF on linux. It doesn't matter on what system you set the property.

See also [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.5)

Comment: On my Windows machine I added the following to my global config file: `* = svn:eol-style=native` after setting `enable-auto-props` to true. But when I do an svn update on the Windows machine I still see that the files are different. When I choose the `e` option to edit the file I see that the remote file has a `^M` at the end of each line. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `enable-auto-props` is for new files only, so it'll use that when `svn add` ing new files. For existing files, you need to manually set the property

Answer (score 0):

To attach the mentioned property manually to a set of existing files run the "svn propset" command (assuming that you have a command line client). 
For example, to attach the property to all cpp files run:

> svn propset -R svn:eol-style native *.cpp